# HTML/CSS, Electron: Tabpane scrollbar does scroll and tabs overflow

Tags: html, css, electron, scrollbar

I am designing an electron application with a tabpane. However when the user makes the window smaller or adds more tabs the scrollbar that is supposed to let users see all the tabs does not work correctly. The scrollbar allows for a little movement but most of the tabs overflow regardless. I have uploaded a stripped down code snippet version of the app here so you can see my problem in more detail.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.window {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.window__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.action-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 44px;
    transition: width 0.2s ease;
}

.action-bar .action-bar__item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}

.action-bar i {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 22px;
}

.action-bar__spacer {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.console {
    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    min-height: 44px;
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
}



.tabpane {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 160px;
    border: solid #1E1E1E;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    background: #333333;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li.tab--active {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background: #1E1E1E;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li i {
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li:hover i, .tabpane .tabpane__tabs li.tab--active i {
    visibility: visible;
}

#draggableTab {
    color: #8D8D8D;
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.9);
    outline: 1px solid rgba(64,64,64,0.9);
    padding: 7px 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10030;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#draggableTab i {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.tabpane__panes {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;  
}

.tabpane__panes li {
    display: none;
}

.tabpane__panes li.pane--active {
    display: initial;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 44px;
    background: #1E1E1E;
}

/* Colors */
.theme--dark {
    color: white;
}

.shade--light {
    background: #333333;
}

.shade--neutral {
    background: #252526;
}

.shade--dark {
    background: #1E1E1E;
}

.shade--darker {
    background: #141516;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="theme--dark shade--dark">
    <div class="window">
        <ul class="action-bar shade--neutral">
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Expand"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Home" data-template="home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Search" data-template="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Download" data-template="download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>Download</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Statistics" data-template="statistics"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Statistics</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Help" data-template="help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Help</li>
            <li class="action-bar__divider shade--light"></li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Lights On"><i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lights On</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Console"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Console</li>
            <li class="action-bar__spacer"></li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Lock"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lock</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Settings" data-template="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>Settings</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="window__content">
            <div class="tabpane">
                <ul class="tabpane__tabs shade--neutral">
                    <li template="home" source="undefined" class="tab--active left">
                        Home
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_1" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 1
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_2" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 2
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_3" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 3
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_4" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 4
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_5" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 5
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_6" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 6
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_7" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 7
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_8" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 8
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="tabpane__panes">
                    <li class="pane--active">
                        <h1>Hello</h1>
                        <div style="max-width: 400px;">
                            <p>Try resizing your browser window until some tabs are hidden and a scrollbar appears.</p>
                            <p>I have removed the JavaScript for this example don't expect buttons to work. The scrollbar however needs to work no matter the height of the console window below the tabs or the width of the action bar to the left.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>page for page 2</li>
                    <li>page for page 3</li>
                    <li>page for page 4</li>
                    <li>page for page 5</li>
                    <li>page for page 6</li>
                    <li>page for page 7</li>
                    <li>page for page 8</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="console console--is-closed shade--darker">
                <div class="console__close"><span class="lnr lnr-cross"></span></div>
                <div class="console__area">
                    <div class="console__resize-bar"></div>
                    <p><span class="console__point">Console> </span><input type="text" class="console__input"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work for you.

just remove the `flex-grow: 1;` from `.window__content` and add `width: calc(100% - 44px);`

`width: calc(100% - 44px);`  == `width: calc(100% - .action-bar[width]);`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.window {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.window__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(100% - 44px);
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.action-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 44px;
    transition: width 0.2s ease;
}

.action-bar .action-bar__item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}

.action-bar i {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 22px;
}

.action-bar__spacer {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.console {
    position: relative;
    height: 44px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    min-height: 44px;
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
}



.tabpane {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 160px;
    border: solid #1E1E1E;
    border-width: 0 1px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    background: #333333;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li.tab--active {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    background: #1E1E1E;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li i {
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.tabpane .tabpane__tabs li:hover i, .tabpane .tabpane__tabs li.tab--active i {
    visibility: visible;
}

#draggableTab {
    color: #8D8D8D;
    background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.9);
    outline: 1px solid rgba(64,64,64,0.9);
    padding: 7px 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    min-width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10030;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#draggableTab i {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.tabpane__panes {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;  
}

.tabpane__panes li {
    display: none;
}

.tabpane__panes li.pane--active {
    display: initial;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 44px;
    background: #1E1E1E;
}

/* Colors */
.theme--dark {
    color: white;
}

.shade--light {
    background: #333333;
}

.shade--neutral {
    background: #252526;
}

.shade--dark {
    background: #1E1E1E;
}

.shade--darker {
    background: #141516;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="theme--dark shade--dark">
    <div class="window">
        <ul class="action-bar shade--neutral">
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Expand"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Home" data-template="home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Search" data-template="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Download" data-template="download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>Download</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Statistics" data-template="statistics"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Statistics</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Help" data-template="help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Help</li>
            <li class="action-bar__divider shade--light"></li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Lights On"><i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lights On</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Console"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Console</li>
            <li class="action-bar__spacer"></li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Lock"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Lock</li>
            <li class="action-bar__item" title="Settings" data-template="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>Settings</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="window__content">
            <div class="tabpane">
                <ul class="tabpane__tabs shade--neutral">
                    <li template="home" source="undefined" class="tab--active left">
                        Home
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_1" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 1
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_2" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 2
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_3" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 3
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_4" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 4
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_5" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 5
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_6" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 6
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_7" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 7
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li template="page_8" source="undefined" class="">
                        page 8
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" title="Close (Ctrl+W)"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="tabpane__panes">
                    <li class="pane--active">
                        <h1>Hello</h1>
                        <div style="max-width: 400px;">
                            <p>Try resizing your browser window until some tabs are hidden and a scrollbar appears.</p>
                            <p>I have removed the JavaScript for this example don't expect buttons to work. The scrollbar however needs to work no matter the height of the console window below the tabs or the width of the action bar to the left.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>page for page 2</li>
                    <li>page for page 3</li>
                    <li>page for page 4</li>
                    <li>page for page 5</li>
                    <li>page for page 6</li>
                    <li>page for page 7</li>
                    <li>page for page 8</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="console console--is-closed shade--darker">
                <div class="console__close"><span class="lnr lnr-cross"></span></div>
                <div class="console__area">
                    <div class="console__resize-bar"></div>
                    <p><span class="console__point">Console> </span><input type="text" class="console__input"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: I'm assuming there's no pure css solution to this if the action bar has a dynamic width? Not that it particularly matters because this is an electron app, but that would still have been preferred, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the width of your tabpane. It should not be 100% (default), since there is the action bar on the left side

```
.tabpane {
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

add

```
width:90%;
```

or whatever 100% - 44px would be

Answer (score 0):

I think;

```
.window__content {
    width: 90%; // add
}
```